# How to install several drivers and configure Windows settings unattended on BYOD devices?

Tags: windows, drivers, installation, uninstall, unattended

For a little project we need to ensure that certain drivers and Windows settings are installed on frequently changing BYOD devices. I am looking for advice on how to achieve this in a simple way. We are all non-coders.

We need to do the following with a single file/install package which is to be downloaded from a website and set all needed drivers and settings up immediately. That file would have to contain all necessary components:

- Install a driver for a printer (connected via USB (zebra or dymo) at a later time)
- Give the printer a distinctive name, make it default printer
- Install driver software for a specific QR scanner
- Make sure that Windos 10 allows to use the Scanner and printer accordingly
- Add a shortcut to a specific website on the desktop
- Has a repair like functionality to just redo the installation to fix any potential issues
- provides the ability to uninstall the drivers and settings at a later time

The website is an existing AWS app that uses the scanner to read a QR code, does some processing and prints out yet another QR code on the zebra or dymo printer

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: I don't really see any other method than building a full-fledged installer package that embeds the other installers and takes care of everything. And installing the printer-drives WITHOUT the printer actually being attached is tricky. Most printer-drivers won't allow this. They like to see the printer during install. Besides that: Windows 10 might throw a fit trying to set the default printer in that case (and setting it default isn't really required at all if it has a specific name). And since this is BYOD: Are your users OK with getting their printer settings messed up?

Comment: Hello @Tonny, I was afraid that it might end up in something like this. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Windows Update settings.

Go to Settings, Update and Recovery and Update Options.

Set "Receive updates for other Microsoft Products" to ON.

Set Automatic Updates to ON (likely the only way it can be).

Set Hours of Operation from 7:00am to 9:00pm  and save all this.

Now Windows will download and install updates but NOT restart until inactive hours are in place. This works well on my machines here.

This approach works for Admin users and Standard Users and works for all Windows Updates and Driver Updates that Windows supports.

Printer depend on the particular printer. Once installed, Windows will keep it up to date.

Windows Repairs are not automatic.

Start with Windows and Driver updates (easy), and then look at your other issues.

Office 365 updates automatically and rarely needs to restart.

Adobe can be set to Automatic Updates and it too will not restart until hours permit. Sometimes (many times) Adobe will update without restarting which is a good thing.

You need to look to your individual apps to see how they fit in.

If necessary, for the users who come in with their own machines, you could write a brief article on basic setups so that you do not need to manage the machines.

Here is a screen shot of the basic settings and then you can go from there.

It could very difficult indeed to manage individual non-domain machines.

[image: Hours of Operation]

Comment: Hello John, thanks for your insight, but I'm afraid I was not quite clear with my description of the requirements. This is not in a business like work environment. People come in and bring their own private laptop and we need to make the connection and setup very simple for them. That is, connecting to the internet, physically connecting scanner and printer, running an install package of some sort and then the users start working immediately. After a couple of hours another person brings in his/her laptop and the whole thing repeats.

Comment: I added a documentation thought to my answer.